# Geth still stucking at synchronizing

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, contract-development, blockchain, ether

I trying to run my eth mainnet node using Geth and prysm but synchronizing process still stucking.

Error:

```
INFO [12-05|02:29:14.015] Syncing: state download in progress      synced=0.36%  state=961.17MiB accounts=828,468@197.22MiB slots=3,547,812@720.93MiB codes=13712@43.02MiB eta=5h39m55.204s
INFO [12-05|02:29:14.329] Forkchoice requested sync to new head    number=18,716,880 hash=6f3350..44c33b finalized=18,716,804
runtime: out of memory: cannot allocate 4194304-byte block (1434615808 in use)
fatal error: out of memory
goroutine 69976 [running]:
runtime.throw({0x2372da2, 0xd})
        runtime/panic.go:1077 +0x4d fp=0x51ee3658 sp=0x51ee3644 pc=0xd31a9d
runtime.(*mcache).allocLarge(0x60109c8, 0x100000, 0x1)
        runtime/mcache.go:236 +0x1c5 fp=0x51ee3684 sp=0x51ee3658 pc=0xd093a5
runtime.mallocgc(0x100000, 0x0, 0x0)
        runtime/malloc.go:1123 +0x5bd fp=0x51ee36d8 sp=0x51ee3684 pc=0xd00edd
github.com/cockroachdb/pebble/internal/rawalloc.New(...)
        github.com/cockroachdb/pebble@v0.0.0-20230928194634-aa077af62593/internal/rawalloc/rawalloc.go:22
github.com/cockroachdb/pebble.(*Batch).grow(0x7ab550e0, 0x4f)
        github.com/cockroachdb/pebble@v0.0.0-20230928194634-aa077af62593/batch.go:1392 +0x9b fp=0x51ee36fc sp=0x51ee36d8 pc=0x146069b
```

Comment: The node seems to be running out of memory.